# I want to display text below date in Calendar View Android

Tags: android, display, calendarview

I am using a calendar view in android but I want to display some numbers/text/string below every date. The way fare is displayed of flights when we try to book a flight via MakeMyTrip or GoIbibo[This is how I wamt to display it in my Calendar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJc4d.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for calendar view and listen to click events of the dates, 
So your view should look like this
 ---parent ----topview ----calendarview
please refer this for more
https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview